# Edit the swagger.json before loading in the UI

Tags: jersey, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

Is there a way to edit the swagger.json before loading it in the ui.
My requirement is to manipulate the swagger.json before loading it in the UI, are there any hooks provided by swagger team to accomplish this

Comment: Did you manually create your Swagger JSON or are you using some library to do this for you?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to manipulate the JSON before it is loaded onto the UI.

The `/api-docs` endpoint is what Swagger calls to serve the documentation.  You can implement custom functionality to take place when this endpoint is served.

For example (in Node.JS):

```
app.get('/api-docs', function(req, res) {
  // manipulate JSON here
  res.json(<return manipulated JSON>);
});
```

You can look in the SwaggerUI `index.js` code to see where this is happening.

**Swagger UI - index.js**

```
var url = window.location.search.match(/url=([^&]+)/);
if (url && url.length > 1) {
  url = decodeURIComponent(url[1]);
} else {
  url = "/api-docs";
}
```

The default url is `/api-docs` so you can just override that.  Also, you can break out your Swagger docs into multiple endpoints by adding a query parameter `url` with the value of your endpoint.

For example, a URL to a second set of Swagger docs for your API could be

`www.mydomain.com?url=/second-set-of-docs`